# messages while loading ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04

I opened up my laptop and first, I see the messages like this. I cant go to my home screen. I am non technical person. Please anyone help me.

[image]

Comment: Those are the verbose boot messages. They are fine unless you are stuck at that screen. If that's the case, it's a problem with your GPU drivers. Try selecting in GRUB advanced options and the previous kernel. If that doesn't work, enter recovery mode and look in the /var/log for anything unusual

Comment: @DanielT Thank you so much. But I have no knowledge in command so much. After I saw that message on my screen, it didnt disappeared itself. Then, I pressed F4. It took me to the terminal, where it tells me that, [01.285510] usb 2-6: Failed to query (GET_DEF) UVC control 8 on unit 1:  -32 (exp.1).  What does that mean?

Comment: I don't know without more context. A USB failure shouldn't normally cause a GPU failure. To boot to the previous kernel, follow the first half (the part with pictures) of https://askubuntu.com/a/1097697/1004020